# Android Deep linking using explicit intent

Tags: android

Currently I am having two web pages, `home` and `about`. The `about` is deep link in that ,so when i click on the link , android gives me the option to use a browser to or my own app to open that link. I would like to explicitly open that link in my app.I don't want list of the apps to handle it. **Is this possible?** Below is my code:

AndroidManifest.xml

```
    <activity
        android:name=".AboutPage"
        android:label="@string/about_page">
        <intent-filter android:label="@string/filter_name">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
            <data android:scheme="http"
                  android:host="appindexing.robscv.info"
                  android:pathPrefix="@string/aboutHTML"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

AboutPage.java

```
public class AboutPage extends ActionBarActivity {

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.about_page);

    // Enable the "Up" button for more navigation options
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    onNewIntent(getIntent());

}

protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent){
    String action = intent.getAction();
    String data = intent.getDataString();
    Log.d(action, data);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short. **No**

#### But

Its coming.
This is a feature scheduled for release in [Android M](https://developer.android.com/preview/overview.html).

All you have to do is add this to the Manifest

```
<intent-filter android:label="@string/filter_name" android:autoVerify="true">
   //...categories etc
</intent-filter>
```

More info [here](http://www.androidpolice.com/2015/05/28/io-2015-android-m-will-support-app-deep-linking-without-that-annoying-selector-prompt/)

---

Just FYI what this will actually do is deep link directly to the app and if multiple apps on a users phone `autoVerify` then it will throw up the prompt.